# 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I am currently using magento 2.4.3 version. I am getting this error when i try to create custom theme in magento. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

To create a Theme, first you need to declare it by creating a `theme.xml` file in the following path. In this file you have to set title for the theme and need to define parent tag if you are willing to inherit another theme.
**app\design\frontend\Themes\yourtheme\theme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
         <title>Theme Title</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
         <parent> Themes/yourtheme</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
    </theme>
```

Once the theme is created you have to register your theme by creating `registration.php` file at below path.
**app\design\frontend\Themes\yourtheme\registration.php**

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend\Themes\yourtheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

Lastly, you have to create `composer.json` file at below location inside your theme folder.
**app\design\frontend\Themes\yourtheme\composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "Themes/yourtheme",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Simply play & with these codes according to your need of creating your own theme in Magento 2.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more question? 
I got error like this after creating custom theme and i try to edit attribute.phtml for once and i got error? Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: include(/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 71

Can anyone help me in this please?

Comment: it clearly says that you have permission issue, try to give that file permission, `sudo chmod -R 777 your_file`

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark as accepted, and upvote would be awsome :)

Comment: I gave permission like ..
cd /var/www/html/<magento install directory>
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + 
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu
chmod u+x bin/magento

(In this order i gave permission)

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 magento_root_dir` just gave permission like this